# add support to new expression scheme language

Tags: scheme, lisp, common-lisp, racket, sicp

I'm new here. I'm soon to have a test, a test language scheme, and I'm getting ready for it.

I have a question that I try to solve for a few hours but do not even understand how to start it.

The question goes like this:

There is a new expression of this form:

`(get-procedure-body <exp>)`

This expression receives a single expression as an argument, evaluates it, and if a user procedure type value is obtained, returns
Her body.

Question in scheme language

Hello everyone, I'm new here. I have a test soon, a test language test, and I'm getting ready for it.
I have a question that I try to solve for a few hours but do not even understand how to start it.

The question goes like this:
There is a new expression of this form:

This expression receives a single expression as an argument, evaluates it, and if a user procedure type value is obtained, returns
Her body.

Here are the possible cases after the revaluation of :

- If the returned value is a user procedure - its body must be returned
- If the returned value is a primitive procedure - “Hidden Implementation! primitive“
- If the value is not a procedure, print "procedure-non: error"

Possible output of the operation of the function:

```
(get-procedure-body f)
> ((display x) (* x y))
(get-procedure-body (lambda (x) (h x)) )
> ((h x))
(get-procedure-body +)
> “primitive! Implementation hidden”
(get-procedure-body 1)
> “error: non-procedure”
(get-procedure-body (+ 1 1))
> “error: non-procedure”
```

The question goes like this:

Add support for body-procedure-get expressions as a kernel expression (write all required changes)

I would be happy if someone could at least help me, I tried to explain myself, if something is not clear, tell me, I will explain more. This is difficult language for me, especially since it does not have much support.

I could not even figure out what to do.

Comment: It sounds as if the question is in the context of a particular interpreter. Do you have a link to the text, where it is described?

Comment: @soegaard Thanks for the help, that's all I have

Comment: Well, what book / course materials are you following? SICP? EoPL? Or something else.

Comment: @soegaard book sicp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Getting the body of a procedure is not part of Scheme and not Common Lisp standard, however if you have made a Scheme interpreter (`eval`) with support for user procedures you most likely have the code in question in your chosen data structure and making the non standard primitive `get-procedure-body` would be exposing the same procedure from the host language. Eg. The book SICP does have something named very similar as part of their interpreter.

As for using Racket I once made this to be able to do something similar:

```scm
#lang racket

(struct proc (src obj)
  #:property prop:procedure
  (struct-field-index obj)
  #:transparent
  #:methods gen:custom-write
  [(define (write-proc x port mode)
     ((case mode
        [(#t) write]
        [(#f) display]
        [else pretty-print])
      (proc-src x)
      port))])

(define-syntax lambda*
  (syntax-rules ()
    ((_ . rest)
     (proc '(lambda* . rest) (lambda . rest)))))

(define test (lambda* (x y) (+ x y)))

test                  ; ==> #(struct:closure (lambda* (x y) (+ x y)) #<procedure>)
(proc-src test)       ; ==> (lambda* (x y) (+ x y))
(proc-obj test)       ; ==> #<procedure>
((proc-obj test) 1 2) ; ==> 3
(test 1 2)            ; ==> 3
```

Now this solution turns the problem upside down. Since I don't have a way to get the source from a system I make syntax that stores the source alongside the procedure object and use a struct feature to package those. As a procedure using `lambda*` would work the same as `lambda` with the exception of introspection.

Comment: Thanks so much for the help, can you tell me where it is in SICP book?

Comment: @masterHaham [Metacircular evaluatetor](https://mitpress.mit.edu/sites/default/files/sicp/full-text/book/book-Z-H-26.html#%_sec_4.1). Look for  `apply` and "representing procedures"